# Change the '*' sign in visual studio editor

Tags: visual-studio

When I open a file in VS to read, when I edit something, on the tab of that file has a '*' sign which indicates that the file has changed.

I've seen some video tutors on VS 2010. They changed it to a red spot.

I just want to know how they can change it or is there some VS add-on to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Nooooo, not the asterisk!  Where's obelix when you need him.

Comment: @HansPassant: In the magic potion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Productivity Power Tools add-in](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) adds this option.

Comment: Thank you! That's the one I'm looking for.